# Make dynamic object global

Tags: c#

My original code:

```
public partial class LineInstance
{
   EventWaitHandle _stopHandle;
   Private int _linenumber;
   // many variable;
   public LineInstance(int linenumber, EventWaitHandle stopper)
   {
      _stopHandle = stopper;
  _linenumber = linenumber;
      // blah
   }    

   private string Menu()
   {
      dynamic api = new Http("http://80.56.16.214/MyServices/MyData.svc");
  var reply = api.GetId(Id: "888");
  var response1 = reply.Response;
  // blah blah
}
 }
```

Now I want to make these

```
dynamic api = new Http("http://80.56.16.214/MyServices/MyData.svc");
var reply = api.GetId(Id: "888");
var response1 = reply.Response;
```

to be global because I want to use in other methods in this class.  I tried move them to the area before class constructor

**updated:**

```
public partial class LineInstance
{
EventWaitHandle _stopHandle;
private int _linenumber;
dynamic api = new Http("http://80.56.16.214/MyServices/MyData.svc");
var reply = api.GetId(Id: "888");
var response1 = reply.Response;
          // blah blah
```

but I got an error:

> Error: “an object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property

How do I modify my code to make them be global?

Comment: What exactly did you put in the area before the constructor?

Comment: Please see my updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your object as `static` if you want to be able to use it without any specific instance of your class

```
public partial class LineInstance
{
private static dynamic api;
EventWaitHandle _stopHandle;
private int _linenumber;
    // many variable;
public LineInstance(int linenumber, EventWaitHandle stopper)
{
_stopHandle = stopper;
_linenumber = linenumber;
    // blah
 }
```

You should provide a `public property` to access the object

```
public static dynamic Api{
 get{ return api; }

}
```

Apart from that, there are no `global` variables in `C#` and you should avoid them by any means!

Comment: Do I have to define others such as reply and response1?

Comment: Is the static keyword in the variable declaration necessary?

Comment: Depends on the case, if you don't declare it `static`, it is bound to an instance of `LineInstance`. If you declare it as `static` it is Independent of a specific instance and shared among all instances of `LineInstance`

Answer (score 0):

To adress these properties from other methods of the class, you don't have to make them static. Your updated code is almost right. Here's what you need to do:

```
public partial class LineInstance
{
   EventWaitHandle _stopHandle;
   Private int _linenumber;
   dynamic api;
   dynamic reply;
   dynamic response1;

   // many variable;
   public LineInstance(int linenumber, EventWaitHandle stopper)
   {
      _stopHandle = stopper;
  _linenumber = linenumber;
      // blah
   }    

   private string Menu()
   {
  api = new Http("http://80.56.16.214/MyServices/MyData.svc");
  reply = api.GetId(Id: "888");
  response1 = reply.Response;
  // blah blah
  }
 }
```

As you see, the only thing I've changed is I initialize the fields in the constructor, not the class body — that way there's no error.

Comment: Error 12 The type or namespace name 'var' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: It seems that I confused api & reply declarations. Edited the answer.

Comment: No you can't place var in that area at all. Only public/private etc.

Comment: It seems you're correct, I don't have a lot of experience with C# runtime/compile-time dynamic typing, use strong typing all the time instead. Sorry for this. But you can still use this declaration with dynamic keyword, or with plain old static typing.